# Does git know which version was being used when?

Tags: git, version-control

I would like to know which version of my code I was using yesterday.  (Or, more specifically, which commit hash).

Does git store this information?  If so, how can it be accessed?

If not, any ideas why not?  And is there some recommended way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "using"? You may be looking for `git reflog`

Comment: git reflog looks somewhat helpful; is there a way to see when HEAD was at each commit?  I would also like to know which branch was checked out at each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reflog` is your friend here.
It shows when the commits associated with branches are updated (or when a non-branch commit is checked-out to the working directory).

You can get more complete information with: `git reflog --date=iso` which will show the reflog entry with date.
Or: `git log -g` which gives the commit date and the full commit message.

The reflog message will also tell you when HEAD is switching branches, but it won't tell you which branch is associated with which commit; that information can change, since branches could be reset at any time.
To find the branches currently associated with a commit, it's easiest to use one of the many GUI tools that look across branches.

Comment: This answer is useful, but I don't think it gives me what I am asking for.  I want to know *when* each entry in the reflog was created, not just when the commit was made.  So ideally there would be a datetime associated with every entry "HEAD@{t}" of the reflog that reflects when HEAD switched from pointing at the previous entry ("HEAD@{t-1}) to that entry ("HEAD@{t}").

Comment: @David - Updated to include --date parameter to show reflog entry date